# Create a MYSQL stored proc to create table in a different database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a stored procedure that can be used across multiple databases but not have to duplicate the stored procedure across all databases.

Example: have stored procedure in BIZ_ADM that can be run and have parameters passed into it that would created the tables and views in another database, BIZ_OPS

CALL `CreateNewEntity1` ('KTC_SHARED', 'TEST1', 'SHARED');

DELIMITER $$

USE `KTC_SHARED`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `CreateNewEntity1`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`192.168.0.%` PROCEDURE `CreateNewEntity1`(IN databaseNameSTR VARCHAR (64), IN entityNameSTR VARCHAR(64), IN extSTR VARCHAR(64))

BEGIN

SET @sqlSTR = CONCAT("CREATE TABLE `TBL_", entityNameSTR, "` (standard fields, etc)

I can do everything if it is to be created in the current database, but does not work when trying to create in a different database.  Hopefully this is clear enough to understand what I am trying to do.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Forgot to mention, don't want to duplicate across multiple databases as this stored procedure will be used frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from CLI window:

```sql
Server version: 8.0.21 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> USE test
Database changed
mysql> CREATE DATABASE test1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.15 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;;
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE test1.createtable (IN db VARCHAR(64), IN tb VARCHAR(64))
    -> BEGIN
    -> SET @sql:=CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', db, '.', tb, '(id INT, val INT);');
    -> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    -> EXECUTE stmt;
    -> DROP PREPARE stmt;
    -> END; ;;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.19 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
Empty set (0.09 sec)

mysql> CALL test1.createtable('test', 'test');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.66 sec)

mysql> SHOW TABLES FROM test;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| test           |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.11 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Akina, Thanks for the response.  Just so that I am clear, I want to be able run the stored procedure from any database and have it create the tables and views in any database I list as parameter.  Will your response do that or do I still have to have the stored procedure in every database?  Thanks

Comment: @dcbk Look carefully - SP is created not in current DB. Nothing prevents to have DB1 as current and execute SP from DB2 which creates a table in DB3.